# How to select an option text matching those of an array value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an array with three elements, Im looping through that array to see the length of it so that it triggers a button click three times to dynamic add input select box. Each array value will go on each added select box and find if it match any option text if it does it have to select it. Below is my code not sure where I'm going wrong

```js
var myArryValues = [
  "Hello World",
  "Javascript",
  "Jquery"
]

for (var i = 0; i < myArryValues.length; i++) {

  var bookIndex = 0;

  $('#bookForm').on('click', '.mynewButton', function() {

      $('.myDropdown').each(function(index) {
        console.log("operatorString", operatorString);
        var operatorCounter = 0;
        var optionCounter = 0;
        $(this).find('option').filter(function() {
          if ($(this)[optionCounter] == myArryValues[operatorCounter]) {
            $(this)[optionCounter].attr('selected', "selected");
            operatorCounter++;
          } else {
            optionCounter++;
          }

        });
      });
      console.log("mynewButton");
      bookIndex++;
      var bookForm = $('#bookForm');
      var $template = $('#bookTemplate'),
        $clone = $template
        .clone()
        .addClass('myDropdown-row')
        .removeClass('hide')
        .attr('data-book-index', bookIndex)
        .attr('id', '');

      bookForm.append($clone);

      // Update the name attributes
      $clone
        .find('[name="myDropdown"]').attr('name', 'myDropdown[' + bookIndex + '].myDropdown').end()

    })
    // Remove button click handler
    .on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
      $(this).parents('.form-group').remove();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="bookForm" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-2 button-div">
      <button type="button" class="mynewButton rule-button">Add New
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- The template for adding new field -->
  <div class="form-group hide" id="bookTemplate">
    <div class="row field-row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <select class="myDropdown" name="myDropdown">
          <option value="Hello World">Hello World</option>
          <option value="Javascript">Javascript</option>
          <option value="Jquery">Jquery</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I created a snippet. Please fix it. For sure do NOT add event handlers inside the loop: `$('#bookForm').on('click', '.mynewButton', function() {` needs to be done only once

Comment: your question is not clear, Please explain it clearly

Comment: Just use `$(this)` instead of `$(this)[optionCounter]` to access option element. to access it value use `.val()` method `$(this).val() == myArryValues[operatorCounter]`. Also agree with @mplungjan, You don't need loop

Comment: @VenkateshKonatham Wha needs to happen is when click on add new button three select drop down will be created as you you array has three element. 1st drop down will need to match Hello world, second Javascript etc

Comment: @Satpal the loop is for the array, so that can I add new drop down based on the array length

Comment: @Satpal thats cool the problem is on all three created drop down, Hello World is selected instead of Javascript and Jquery. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you mean , after creating dropdown ,it's value should be selected as the index of array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This on your click function

```js
var data = ['bar','baz'];
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var s = $('<select id="'+i+'"/>');
        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
          if (i==j) {
            $('<option />', {value: data[j], text: data[j],selected:'selected'}).appendTo(s);
          }else{
            $('<option />', {value: data[j], text: data[j]}).appendTo(s);
          }
        }
        s.appendTo('body');
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thats the answer I was looking for, I just tweak to my design

Comment: the code works well the issue I have is if clone the div all the select drop down are in one div and another instead of first selected on a first clone div etc etc

Comment: I can't get what you are saying? you want each select-box in separate div ??